# Piwik Analytics on Askubuntu

Tags: support

Please can someone explain why it is not possible to change the analytics on this site to the open source tool Piwik Analytics or to explain why the current analytics is being used.

Comment: Because [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com).

Comment: I've used Piwik myself for small sites, but I doubt it could handle the traffic of the whole SE network (~20-25 million page views per day)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not something under our control. The site is part of Stack Exchange.

Like a lot of sites, our analytics is split between internal metrics (view counts, etc) that the moderators can see, and Google Analytics, which we cannot.

I don't foresee that changing any time soon.

Comment: The moderator analytics are based on the Google Analytics data

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah I thought they might be while posting but wasn't sure. We don't have raw access to the data though.